# A mistake in QueryBuilder brings all entries from elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, query-builder

We have a Java Spring Boot application that constructs queries to elasticsearch db with a programmatic way according to business parameters via `QueryBuilder`, similar to a criteria builder in sql.

The problem is that a mistake in the code can actually produce a query that brings everything from the database, like a `select *` in sql.

eg `QueryBuilders.boolQuery();`

creates

```
"bool" : { 
"adjust_pure_negative" : true, 
"minimum_should_match" : "1", 
"boost" : 1.0 
}
```

This can be checked by `hasClause()` function and cancel the query.

However, a query like this will not be blocked `QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery());`

1. Is there any option to forbid the elastic from executing queries like `select *` ?
2. Any suggestions on how to validate a final `QueryBuilder` object ?

Comment: You have the full power in your application code to detect this. For instance, increasing a counter every time you add a real constraint and not sending the query if that counter is still 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent Elasticsearch from executing queries that can potentially return all documents (like a "SELECT *" query in SQL), you can set a maximum limit on the number of results retrieved by a query. This can be done using the **size** parameter, which limits the number of results returned by the query. For example, you can set the **size** parameter to a reasonable limit (e.g., 1000) to prevent Elasticsearch from retrieving all documents in the index.

Additionally, you can also use the **validate API** in Elasticsearch to validate a query before executing it. The **validate API** allows you to check whether a query is syntactically correct and whether it returns any results. You can use this API to validate the QueryBuilder object generated by your application. This will ensure that it does not return all documents from the index.